# How can I enable/disable desktop effects for the current window in KDE?

Tags: kde, kwin

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut or option to quickly toggle whether an application/window is affected by the compositor. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can toggle desktop effects with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was looking for a way to do it for just one window, though.